# Repeat defined pipeline for other environment

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, release-management

For below Pipeline, if selected environment is 'dev' then after completing pipeline it should promt and deploy to other environments i.e. 'qa' or 'staging' as well.

How do we achieve this in JenkinsFile? Simply putting if conditions OR any other plugins such as 'build promotion' ?

The purpose of this is to replicate any changes to all environments.

```
{ 

    properties([
        parameters([choice(choices: "dev\nqa\nstg", description: 'Environment?', name: 'environment')])
    ])

    pipeline {
        agent any

        stages {
            stage('Build') {
                steps {
                   echo "Building..${params.environment}"
                }
            }
            stage('Test') {
                steps {
                    echo "Testing..${params.environment}"
                } 
            }
            stage('Deploy') {
                steps {
                    echo "Deploying..${params.environment}"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```